# Users not willing to format or express properly: what to do?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I just came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796782/difference-in-output-between-two-different-platformunix-and-linux

The user is asking something quite general based on a script he does not show. I asked for some updates:

> we cannot suggest solutions blindly: how does the script look like?

and he then [replied in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796782/difference-in-output-between-two-different-platformunix-and-linux#comment47722010_29796782):

> foreach my $key (sort keys %bhash){ if(!exists $ahash{$key}){ my $tmp
>   =$bhash{$key}.';'.'ID=NA'; print FP "$tmp\n"; }else{ my $count=@{$ahash{$key}}; my $chk1=${$ahash{$key}}[0];
>   for($c=1;$c

Since the user has some reputation, I checked his profile and saw this is the 8th question he asks. None of them were accepted even though they all have answers. Also, the OP does not dare to even use the `Edit` button to post proper questions and other users end up formatting it for him.

What should we do in this case? Do we have to tirelessly keep editing his posts, suggesting to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", etc, or we should just close the question as "unclear what you are asking" and hope that this will trigger the user's interest to see how to behave properly.

I have the feeling that we should go for the second option, since we are probably solving his issues without him showing any effort.

## Update

The user seems to be behaving exactly the same: look at [one of his last questions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30748502/1) before somebody formatted it. I wrote [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938075/pentaho-excel-sheet-reading-error#comment48004606_29938075) to the user and I think we are failing to do something relevant here: he knows that we will end up formatting his very bad questions, so he doesn't have to care at all.

Comment: You can leave a comment to format code and adding the code in question with the link of How to ask. I think this is good way.

Comment: Have you tried asking the person to edit the code into the post? I usually don't do it for them but tell them how. "No, please use the edit button below the post and add the code there. It is awfully hard to read in comments." If the information needed to answer isn't provided, simply close as "off-topic: help with debugging requires code, clear problem statement blah blah"

Comment: @codeMagic OK, I just did. The point here is that this user is not showing any interest in learning how to ask properly, so the basic comments addressed to the new users seem to be useless for him.

Comment: He's still only been a member for just under a month a 7 questions isn't *a whole lot*. There were a couple comments suggesting to edit on other posts and one where someone did it for him. IMO, he really may not fully "get it" yet. Personally, I think explaining *how*, as you did in your last comment to him, is the way to go and see what happens. If he still isn't editing the code from comments to the post, I would continue to VTC as per my previous comment.

Comment: If the question is unclear without the comments then voting to close it on that basis is perfectly reasonable. But as @codeMagic suggests, this user is pretty new and if may be worth giving him/her a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since this behaviour is quite common in the tags I normally check (bash, shell, linux...) I somehow get tired from time to time. I added a couple of constructive comments to the question, let's see if the user wants to go one step beyond and improve the way he presents his questions.

Comment: I'd suggest (/have done) voting to close as Off-topic > Questions asking for debugging... There is nowhere near enough information to answer the question as it stands - hopefully it will: 1. Get put on-hold. 2. The OP reads the close message (well, maybe) and the articles it links to (right?) 3. The OP edits the question accordingly. 4. It gets reopened and answered. Call me hopelessly optimistic...

Comment: @jonrsharpe, In my experience it often doesn't get reopened, so OP goes and asks a new similar one, and old closed question sticks around forever, together with then new one.

Comment: @JonasCz well that's a different problem to fix! This question will get auto-deleted if it isn't reopened - see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/248731 (he said, apparently speaking too soon...)

Comment: @JonasCz in fact, the OP just removed the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the question is unclear without the comments (comments should be considered temporary) then voting to close it on that basis is perfectly reasonable and the correct thing to do. It may also be worth a downvote, remember that the tooltip on the downvote button says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

If the user continues to behave this way, his/her questions will get down-voted or closed and they will pretty quickly get post-banned (which effectively solves the problem)

However, as suggested in the comments, this user is pretty new and if may be worth giving him/her a chance of redemption by mentioning in the comments how to make good questions.

Answer (score 9):

I usually comment first, suggesting editing relevant information into the original post. I prefer the  OP to do this, because if I take their snippet and reformat it myself, I might make the problem disappear.

If they've not done this in a timely fashion (this varies depending how impatient I'm feeling) I'll try and do it myself. If I conclude I cannot, because the information is incomplete, I'll downvote or vote to close (depending).

Comment: Interesting answer. What I am missing here is the point I was doing in my question: what if the user does not show any attempt to "learn to ask" and keeps asking bad formatted, too generic questions, with extra information in comments?

Comment: @fedorqui: vote to close/downvote as appropriate. The problem will fix itself eventually - either the user learns, or the question ban kicks in.

Comment: I'm happy enough to put a new member's code in a question into a code block when required, if it seems like they don't understand how to do that, or what code blocks are, and as long as I can do that without modifying the code. But for more important issues, if the OP of an unclear question doesn't respond to the helpful comments of myself or others in a timely fashion, I generally vtc &/or downvote.

Comment: FWIW, I mostly frequent the Python tag, where code in comments is even more of a hassle than most other languages, due to the significance of whitespace. It's often impossible to transfer such code correctly to the question while preserving the author's intent. OTOH, the upside is that all but the newest Python programmers realise that whitespace is significant in Python, so they usually cooperate when asked to move the code and rarely make that mistake twice.

Comment: IMHO, this nuanced approach is just right. If the question _could_ be useful, then on a time-available basis, we should do what we can to get it there. It's also an avenue to "teach by example", showing the OP what their question _should_ have looked like. On the whole, SO doesn't have the bandwidth to go around fixing _every_ broken question, so if the OP doesn't get with the program, they will on average fail to find answers to their questions (i.e. "punishment enough"). But their failure shouldn't be a reason for SO itself to not gain beneficial content.

Comment: Yes, it's not feasible to fix and improve every question. But I have a lot more tolerance for people who are working in English when it's not their primary language than people who are just too lazy :) (You can tell the difference quite easily).