# How do you stop a user from posting bad questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, users

I'm trying to help somebody and I notice that they haven't done any research on their own. For example I one time answered somebody's question and they commented: *"I'm just not sure how to use it correctly from the first keystroke until deploy"*. Of course I want to help, so I gave him some links to help him do it, and he seemed kind of offended that I didn’t spell it out for him. Still got some reputation for that, so not really my biggest problem.

Another time I tried to help somebody else and asked him what he had tried, and if he could give some code. He answered *"I don't know how to do in WPF. I want the code for that only. How to do."* again clearly he didn't try anything and I again gave some links to help him figure it out on his own.

Especially this last guy was somebody I wanted to report. When I looked at his profile and the other questions he asked all of them where “How to do”. Rarely any of them had some code, or some description what he tried. I know that in the help center there are some guidelines for on topic questions. The third off topic example is this:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

So he is off-topic, so I flagged him once (which is still pending). When I noticed he was doing this regularly I wanted a more effective way of reporting these questions, but it’s not possible to report a user, so I ended up here. One advice I saw one a related topic was that you should report a question and then mention this issue. I took this advice and flagged his latest question, but it was just denied.

So how could I report this kind of behavior? Or some advice how to deal with these kind of people would be nice.

Comment: Once the person gets enough downvotes and closures, the user will be banned/throttled from asking questions.

Comment: Downvote them.  They get question-banned.  They open a new account.  They post bad questions.. rinse, repeat.

Comment: "..  he seemed kind off offended that I didn’t spell it out for him .." That's what I call "spoon feeding, followed by '.. but this soup is too *hot*!'."

Comment: We could try [educating them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) in a more effective manner instead?!

Comment: Just a note, don't go to the user's profile and serially downvote everything - even if they are all bad. The system can't distinguish that from vote-fraud and will reverse the votes.

Comment: @MartinJames Downvoting requires 125 rep.

Comment: Well guys take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31248577/1389394). There should also be a way to prevent from posting answers like this: a jQuery answer for a VBA, Excel Question!

Comment: @Mysticial - What is the threshold for that?

Comment: @Dzyann: that is a closely guarded secret, to avoid people taking deliberate (dis)advantage of it by serial voting close to, but not crossing, that threshold.

Comment: @Tanner - most of them don't want educating, they just want their questions answered ASAP.  An attempt at education would take more work that actually writing their code for them, so my approach is to do neither.

Comment: @apaul34208 - Sure, but the OP is already at 89 rep so they may get to 125 fairly soon. It's also good to let other people looking at this question know that this is the case.

Comment: Things are not what they seem, the user you are complaining about has 5K rep.  Mostly from answers with some of them highly upvoted.  He's not going to get banned or throttled, "reporting" will have no effect.  He put a bounty on his question and did not get much traction out of it.  Questions like this *used* to get elaborate answers but most of the SO users that did so stopped contributing.  It is kinda up to you now, sorry.

Comment: @Dzyann About three or four votes in quick succession will typically trigger it. It doesn't take much.

Comment: @TylerH - Thanks for the clarification. Does it also trigger some kind of penalization?

Comment: @Dzyann Well the votes are reversed, and if it is severe enough or is otherwise brought to a moderator's attention, they can put your account on ice for a while or warn you with a special moderator's message, reserved for serious offenses.

Comment: @TylerH - Thanks, I will be careful, I have down-voted/flagged a couple of times a couple of posts by a single user, but with good intentions, I don't want get in trouble for such a thing.

Comment: This is a very interesting point. I recently asked [Users not willing to format or express properly: what to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291083/1983854) because I was observing the same pattern in a user behaviour. We have the tendency to give a bigger bunch of help to new users, and this can lead us to "create a monster" (a help vamp) that knows that we will eventually clean the question and provide some good answer, no matter the effort they put on their side. However, the best is to provide some links in the comments to How to ask.

Comment: You can 'report a user' by using an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on any of their posts and explaining the situation. Although I can't guarantee that this is appropriate here, as moderators might expect that this will sort itself out through 'the system' (enough negative-voted questions => automatic ban).

Comment: I think a bigger problem is bad answers. I see answers such as "Go read up on activity life cycle and when you come back you will know the answer or ask a different question" Or another one. "I don't think you know how adapters work. You should read tutorials on adapters first." Stack Overflow is at it's heart a question AND ANSWER site, yet users are behaving like they are above answering questions. There's a reason users get offended when people don't answer questions. Imagine calling Microsoft help desk and being told you need to learn to use your computer before you can ask that question.

Comment: The difference between a help desk and SO is that a help desk is purely for quick fixes and SO is a community that helps you learn new stuff. In this learning process you do have to do stuff for yourself. Ofcourse you should be send in the right direction, but I actually like those kind of answers.

Comment: @Redshirt - If you see those as actual answer posts instead of comments, go ahead and flag them. But the quotes you have aren't rude. It's not wrong to tell someone that they're in over their head or that they're trying to start from the middle. I've seen questions from people who say they're brand new to programming but want to re-create YouTube from scratch. You can't answer something like that.

Comment: @Redshirt - This is less like calling Microsoft because you can't figure out where a setting is in Word and more like calling Microsoft because you want to be able to use a Word document as an online database. They wouldn't try to figure out how to do that, they'd tell you to use a different product.

Comment: Coming from someone with not many fake help points, I notice that I rarely get up votes or any kind of recognition for having well thought out questions. I try to add a ton of information with my questions including errors, example code, and expected output and I almost never get any kind of +. Perhaps these folks think it is easier to just ask without any supporting documentation because there is rarely a reward for detailed questions?

Comment: @Aaron - I think that's why there's the Electorate badge. It's harder to differentiate questions that are good vs OK than it is to differentiate bad questions from OK question. Or maybe I'm just stingy? I don't want to up vote a question in a technology I'm unfamiliar with and have someone who is familiar with it be all, "How did this get up voted?!?!"

Answer (score 108, accepted):

When you come across extremely low quality questions that don't meet the sites standards, the first and most important thing to do is to *not post a low quality answer*, which is exactly what you did in the first two cases.  When you attempt to answer the low quality questions you only create more problems for the site, and you encourage people to continue posting more low quality questions.

These are all good things to be doing when you come across low quality questions:

1. Downvote them.
2. Vote (or flag) for closure for an appropriate reason. It sounds like most of the questions in your examples were Too Broad, although other reasons may have applied, and other questions you come across may merit closure for different reasons.
3. Comment on the question to explain how it can be improved, what it's missing, or why it's not answerable/of high quality.

If a user repeatedly asks low quality questions, and as a result their questions are regularly closed/downvoted, then they'll end up being automatically banned from asking questions, so taking these actions is important as it helps inform the question ban algorithm of the fact that the user is posting low quality content.

Comment: TL;DR: -1 + VTC

Comment: I would just add that commenting is optional, and if the questioner tries to engage you in fixing their problem via comments rather than fixing their question, point out that's what the question is for, and walk away if they keep asking for more and more.

Comment: While optional, commenting does go a long way in improving the long term health of SO in helping acclimate new users to the culture. Many are just ignorant of the focus of SO as opposed to other programming forums.  If you start by emphasizing you're as much interested in them getting help as they are "I think what you're asking might be a good question if you can provide more details and narrow focus", and follow that up with carefully articulated suggestions, or linking to specific FAQs/help/guides. This can go with down votes, which can always be reversed if they provide a good edit.

Comment: Thank you, I should indeed just walk away like Mike McCaughan said.

Comment: @AaronLS - Helping new users is good but this particular question is about users who are aggressively *refusing* help.

Comment: @BSMP Yes the specific case is, but Servy's response addresses the more generic question in the title of "How do you stop a user from posting bad questions?" and as he mentioned a very effective part of that is to comment.  If this meta question were to be referenced in the future people should keep in mind commenting can be a healthy part of improving SO.

Comment: I think the trying to improve the question via commenting is also the first step. If they don't respond the next step would be downvoting. The last step would be to flag/vote for closure and walk away. I can't downvote yet, so I would skip that part. Also what Servy said it's important not to encourage people to continue posting more low quality questions, and I think I still have to learn that.

Comment: @Kyra: Don't delay signalling to others and the system (unless it's just a small thing), just because the OP *might* correct it. If he does, you can retract your vote, or even vote the other way *if that's now warranted*.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you answer in a comment to one of these questions, you're probably doing the same amount of harm as posting an answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator the thing is that I can't downvote yet, and I'm also limited in flags. So basicly I just have to try to help them via comments, and if they don't do anything themself just walk away.

Comment: @Kyra: Sorry, didn't check your rep. Time will correct that, hopefully soon enough.

Comment: @Kyra The fact that you don't have enough rep to downvote or close vote means that you can't currently make use of those tools.  When you do have the rep to make use of them, they are actions you should be taking as soon as you recognize that the question is of low quality or isn't suitable for the site.  When you can use them you shouldn't be waiting to use them until after its too late for them to be helpful.

Comment: Adam Smith and Darwin work hand in hand in these cases.

Comment: Frustratingly, the site is somewhat unwieldy when you have very low rep.  You'll need to build up rep slowly to the point where you reach the coveted 2k (I think it was?) where you can start to contribute meaningfully to the quality assurance aspects of the site.  If it's any consolation, I remember reaching that level of rep within a few weeks when I started on SO (but that's a few years ago, and rep build seems to depend heavily on which tags you are active in).

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately you got bitten by a help vampire. It happens to all of us, because lets face it - we wouldn't be answering questions if we didn't want to help (or maybe we're just rep whoring, but the result is the same).

These are parasites who are using stack overflow as a way of getting work done without effort.

Sadly - answering their questions creates a self perpetuating cycle where your help encourages them to do it again. So downvote, vote to close and move on. Ideally don't answer or delete your answer too.

It can be easy to get caught out though - in the spirit of generosity, you might have a difficult time telling the difference between a newbie or someone working in a different language and a parasite.
If you're suspicious, it's often the case that said help vampires don't even bother with the bare minimum courtesy of marking a question answered (or upvote, because they can't). So 'feeding' them is a pretty poor way of repwhoring too :).

Don't sweat it too much - we all make mistakes. Sometimes it'll help to leave a comment explaining why you've declined to answer - refer them to the relevant help sections. Other times it's just wasted noise.

Sticking with remembering - a good question promotes good answers, and these make future reference points. A bad question, even with a decent answer isn't going to be much future use. And that's what we're doing here - making an archive of 'good stuff'.

Comment: Wouldn't "someone working in a different language" say "In Python, I'd use x, y, and z. How do I do it in JavaScript with Node?"

Comment: I was meaning someone who doesn't speak English as their first language. It can be hard to articulate a question on an English speaking site, so I'm generally more forgiving of it.